# Logo is not showing in Magento2 mobile responsive view

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, logo

I am facing issue in mobile responsive view.In desktop view Logo is showing but in mobile the image is not showing please help to find this issue.

Comment: please share your frontend link or any screenshot

Comment: Check if any css is applied for mobile view.

Comment: I referred this below link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104949/magento2-store-logo-look-distorted-on-mobile-version.I tried but it's not working

Comment: please pass your site URL so I can investigate the issue . Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento2 store logo look distorted on mobile version](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104949/magento2-store-logo-look-distorted-on-mobile-version)

Comment: check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#theme_logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could come from several things;

1) Maybe you have some config in your theme settings to hide it

2) Maybe you have a hidden mobile col bootstrap something like `hidden-xs hidden-sm`

3) Maybe your CSS is wrong

4) Try to add this image responsive class `img-responsive` to your logo image class like: `...title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo img-responsive">...`

5) Clean the Magento & browser cache.