# Magento 2.3.4: How to keep AMP enabled yet allow the homepage to load its images for mobile devices?

Tags: magento2.3, frontend, home-page, mobile-device

How do I ensure mobile devices can load the homepage with all its images with AMP enabled? The homepage for mobile devices is missing all the images present on the homepage unless the AMP is disabled from the Magento admin.

Comment: Check this post answer if it helps! https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/182040

Comment: The post you referred me to didn't work. Is there anything else that you suggest?